# Vuejs Transition works for normal, in-out but component disappear if using mode out-in

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router4

So i tried to use Transition on routes changed. It works fine for normal transition, transition with `mode='in-out'` but when i tried to use `mode='out-in'` then when click link the current element did have the transisiton effect but then the destination route not show up like, disappear. i check on dev tools the node of that componenets not registered on the html tree also. It show now bug, no log no nothing so i don't know how to find the culprit. I recorded some videos hopefully someone might show me a way  to find it.

Video 1: Normal Transition with no mode applied: https://streamable.com/ln6z5g

Video 2: Transition with `mode='in-out'` applied: https://streamable.com/ta7gfw

=> The problem happend here:
Video 3: Transition with `mode='out-in'` applied: https://streamable.com/ta7gfw

Try to find the problem, see what cause it but found none. Try to log onMounted, onUnMounted but no log show mean it not registered. Try to create a blank brandnew vue project and tried it but everything works fine. Try to look for html tree and vue dev tools but got nothing.

I found a thread about leaving a comment infront of template make transition count it as another node but i check mine and i have none. [Link to topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76759575/vue-js-component-not-transitioning-out-even-with-mode-out-in)

I would expect this transition effect will fade element A out and element B fade in. But instead elemant A out and element B would never come in.